# RTK query disable cache

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have three buttons and text near it

[button item_count]

**[red 1]** - [blue 2] - [yellow 3]

- item 1
- item 2
  ...
- item 123

When we click on each button we see different items.

I fetch everything using rtk-query, so the response from the server is(for example, **red** is clicked):

```
{
    red : 1,
    blue : 2,
    yellow : 3,
    data : [...]
}
```

On every button click I get the newest data;

**The problem:**

1. On page load:

[red 1] - [blue 2] - [yellow 3]

2. In Database, I add new item to **red** section
3. I select **blue** button the buttons will be:
   [red 2] - **[blue 2]** - [yellow 3] - because I re-fetched everything when selected **blue button** and count increased for red;

**BUT**

4. When I click **red**, for a second I see old count 1; I see [red 1] then when it stops fetching data I see [red 2]

**THE SOLUTION I CAME UP:**

The solution is to use `keepUnusedDataFor:0`

I think the problem is with the cache. Also, my endpoint uses `refetchOnMountOrArgChange : true`

Maybe there is a better solution for this problem?

Comment: Hi 

Can you show an example how you are calling your API ?